# How do I initialise a std::array field inside a struct with the contents of a variable length sequence container?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a struct which in an extremely simplified representation looks like this:

```
struct Flags {
    const std::array<unsigned int, 8> flags;

    Flags(std::vector<unsigned int> initialFlagValues) : flags(initialFlagValues) {}
};
```

Which of course does not compile. For the purposes of my program, I'd like to initialise an arbitrary number of elements in `flags`, depending on the length of a parameter (`std::vector`, C-style array, or otherwise) passed into the constructor of the struct.

Now I'd like to use a `std::array` inside the struct, as the struct itself is created many times (so a `std::vector` would not be ideal here due to many allocations/deallocations), but the number of values within `flags` that need to be initialised is not always the same.

Is there a way I can initialise a specific number of fields in `flags` depending on the size of the sequence container passed as a parameter into the constructor?

Comment: What should happen if `initialFlagValues` is too large? What should happen to the remaining elements if `initialFlagValues` is smaller than `8`, are they supposed to be set to zero or left indeterminate? Do you want specifically initialization or would assignment be fine as well? The last question doesn't matter if the element type is `unsigned int`, but might matter for types that are not assignable.

Comment: Note that making a data member `const` is a decision that comes with a *lot* of repercussions (no assignment, for example). You should only do it when there is a demonstrated need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a helper function, perhaps in the form of a lambda:

```
Flags(std::vector<unsigned int> initialFlagValues) :
    flags([](const auto& init) {
             std::array<unsigned int, 8> flags;
             // bounds check omitted for brevity
             std::copy(init.begin(), init.end(), flags.begin());
             return flags;
         }(initialFlagValues))
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the helper function can be a delegated constructor

```
struct Flags
 {
   std::array<unsigned int, 8u> const flagsArr;

   template <std::size_t ... Is>
   Flags (std::vector<unsigned int> iFV, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
      : flagsArr{ Is < iFV.size() ? iFV[Is] : 0u ... }
    {}

   Flags (std::vector<unsigned int> iFV)
      : Flags{iFV, std::make_index_sequence<8u>{}}
    {}
};
```

You can generalize with for generic types supporting operator `[]` and `std::size()` (so also C-style arrays) as follows

```
struct Flags
 {
   std::array<unsigned int, 8u> const flagsArr;

   template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
   Flags (T const & iFV, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
      : flagsArr{ Is < std::size(iFV) ? iFV[Is] : 0u ... }
    {}

   template <typename T>
   Flags (T const & iFV)
      : Flags{iFV, std::make_index_sequence<8u>{}}
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` is an aggregate.  That means the only way to initialized it is with a *braced_init_list* (`{}`).  There is no way to convert a `std::vector` into a *braced_init_list* so one thing you can do is to use a loop inside the constructor like

```
Flags(std::vector<unsigned int> initialFlagValues) : flags{} // zero out flags
{
    auto size = std::min(initialFlagValues.size(), flags.size())
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        flags[i] = initialFlagValues[i];
}
```

This will nessecitate that `flags` be non-const.  If that is a change you can't make, then you'll need to make `initialFlagValues` a `std::array`, or use a helper function to return an array that you can use to initialize `flags` with.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do everything at (almost) compile-time, with no iterations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

struct Omg {
        static constexpr std::size_t SIZE = 8;

        template<class Container> Omg(Container &&c)
                : Omg(std::forward<Container>(c), std::make_index_sequence<SIZE>{})
        {}

        void omg() const {
                for(auto i: array) std::cout << i << ' ';
                std::cout << '\n';
        }
private:
        template<class C, std::size_t... is> Omg(C &&c, std::index_sequence<is...>)
                : array{get<is>(std::forward<C>(c))...}
        {}

        template<std::size_t i, class C> static constexpr auto get(C &&c) {
                return i < std::size(c)? c[i] : 0;
        }

        std::array<int, SIZE> array;
};

int main() {
        Omg(std::vector<int>{0, 1, 2, 3}).omg();
        int nyan[] = {42, 28, 14};
        Omg(nyan).omg();
}
```